# Sublime Text 2 HTML tag indentation

Tags: html, sublimetext2, auto-indent

So in Java, when I type {} and press enter between them, Sublime would auto indent it so it's like

```
  {
      blah blah
  }
```

However, I am now coding some things in HTML and have been bothered by something. When I type tags with auto complete, and press enter, then it looks like:

```
  <div>
  </div>
```

with the cursor in front of the second line. I know I can just not type the closing tags for proper indentation but how can I make it to mimic the java auto indent? I saw online videos of people using Sublime Text 2 and they got it like that but I'm having trouble. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: In your sublime go to view and than scroll down to indentation tick mark indent using spaces and even tick mark tab width 4 or whatever you like

Comment: @RadiantAhmed it's already that. It works fine with Java just not HTML